# Запись ключей и значений в словарь в цикле

Tags: python, словари

Хочу чтобы при каждом прохождении цикла в словарь добавлялась новая пара ключ-значение, а добавляется только одна, последняя.

```
alldata=np.load(fn)
    spec_chan=np.shape(alldata)[1]
    snrs = {}
    for aver in range(start,stop):
        periods=per*aver
        data_aver=np.zeros((aver,spec_chan), dtype=np.complex)
        data=alldata[0:periods]
        for i in range(periods/aver):
            data_aver[0:aver]+=data[i*aver:(i+1)*aver]
        ifft_data=abs(fft.ifft(data_aver,axis=-2))
        section=ifft_data[s,0:]
        section=section.tolist()
        A=max(section)
        index_from=section.index(A)-5
        index_to=section.index(A)+5
        del section[index_from:index_to]
        average=np.mean(section)
        st_deviation=np.std(section)
        SNR=(A-average)/st_deviation
        snrs[aver]=SNR
        print snrs
```

Comment: а чему равны `start` и `stop`?

Comment: задаются из командной строки, ну например 250 и 350.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: похоже в данном случае без воспроизводимого примера и того что вы хотите получить на выходе вам будет трудно помочь... [Как наиболее эффективно задать вопрос, связанный с обработкой и/или анализом данных (например: по Pandas / Numpy / SciPy / SciKit Learn / SQL).](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/7060/)